# Precompiling: Directory doesn't exists '~\projectName\obj\Release\AspnetCompileMerge\Source\Config' C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio

I am trying to publish an ASP.NET MVC web app with precompilation. While publishing the app the get the error that `Directory doesn't exist Directory '~\projectName\obj\Release\AspnetCompileMerge\Source\Config'. Failed to start monitoring file changes.`

The error is coming with both `Non-Updatable User Interface` and with `Updatable User Interface`, but when if I try to turn off precompilation, the app is published successfully.

I have looked into [this](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/b903b64d-c505-4180-8461-c9627a95768a/i-am-getting-the-message-an-error-occurred-loading-a-configuration-file-directory?forum=wcf) form, and have given permission to `IUSER` but the error still exists. I couldn't find `ASPNET` so was not able to add.

[Ref1](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/706266/error-when-publishing-web-app-to-folder-in-visual.html)

Answer (score 0):

Applications connection string was not stored in the `web.config` file but was in `Config\connectionStrings.config` file on root level of the project. I was using [configSource](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.configuration.sectioninformation.configsource?view=netframework-4.8) to refer the file from `web.config`. `Config\connectionStrings.config` was not included in the project and was included in git `.ignore` file.

When I included the `Config\connectionStrings.config` file in the solution and built the project with precompilation, everything worked as expected.